# In CloudFlare, present cached page only if cookie is not set

Tags: cookies, cloudflare

I'm trying to prevent CloudFlare from hitting our servers if a user is not logged in, but instead to get the cached object if possible.  We're setting a cookie ('email') if the user is logged in, and clearing it when the user is logged out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

In order to do this you can use a feature called "Bypass Cache on Cookie". This allows you to specify a Regex string of what type of cookie you want to Bypass:

[image: Bypass Cache on Cookie]

When used in conjunction with a Cache Everything Page Rule, you can use this setting to cache anonymous page views but bypass the cache when a cookie exists.

Further reading:

- [Caching Anonymous Page Views](https://blog.cloudflare.com/caching-anonymous-page-views/)
- [How do I cache static HTML?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-)
- [Technical Details: Bypass Cache Cookie (Business and Enterprise Only)](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-#business)

Comment: hello, I cant see this "Bypass Cache on Cookie" in cloudfare ..!!

Comment: Are you on a Business or Enterprise plan? As described, this feature is only available on those plans.

Comment: ohhh I use Free plan, in this case, should I just use Cache Level = cache everything & Edge cache TTL = 1month  ?
I also set "browser cache expiration' to default (4 hrs) , is these setting OK for me ?

Comment: No, you should not. If you try to Cache Everything without using Bypass Cache on Cookie you'll end up with cache collisions.

Comment: arghh , its confusing for me. I ONLY used "browser cache expiration' to default (4 hrs)  and I set a page rule for "cache everything"=*example.com/* , is it ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Business plan only using page rules.

More info [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-).