# Wordpress visitors see and access admin login

Tags: wordpress, security, caching, cloudflare

When visitors access this website, some of them are seeing the admin username at the top, and in some cases can click on it and log in to the back end. It is running the most current version of WordPress (4.9.4) with all plugins up to date. CloudFlare caching, Autotomize plugin and the WP Super Cache. I have encouraged the users to log-out after every post, but can't guarantee they always do.

I recently installed Redis Object Cache, but to be honest, I am not 100% certain what it does. I want to believe this is not a caching CloudFlare issue since I can not duplicate it on my end.

[image: live example screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**First possibility:** The user on the other end is actually logged in, and their account "Role" is set to one which allows the admin bar to be displayed.  Any user that registers for the site could, in fact, have access to the admin bar, even if it's not appropriate for them as a "post comment writer," for instance.

If this is the case, then this technique may help: [How to Disable WordPress Admin Bar for All Users Except Administrators](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-wordpress-admin-bar-for-all-users-except-administrators/)

**Second possibility:** Cloudflare is caching and presenting cached pages, independent of whether or not a cookie is set.

Ideally, pages would be cached for visitors who are not logged in, but logged in visitors often need to have pages presented slightly differently.  Conversely, you would not want one of these latter pages presented to an unauthenticated user.

This seems to be a problem that has been addressed on StackOverflow in the context of CloudFlare and Wordpress, but it may require a paid CloudFlare subscription to access the settings: [In Cloudflare, Present Cached Page Only If Cookie Is Not Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686709/in-cloudflare-present-cached-page-only-if-cookie-is-not-set)

Comment: Thanks, Seth! None of these visitors have any kind of role within the organization. I have gone through and cleared all the cache and will work on disabling the WordPress admin bar.